# How to photograph a tire tread without getting a bulge effect?

Tags: product-photography, perspective

I'm a beginner in photography and have been assigned to photograph a series of tire styles. I have all the equipment needed, am just looking for advise on how to photograph a tire straight on without getting this sort of bulge.
Would an infinite focus help this problem or should I purchase a different soft or lens? This is what I am trying to achieve and this is what is being achieved. Also any other quick advise in general is appreciated!

What I am achieving:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you do **not** have all the equipment needed. It would be very helpful to at least mention what equipment you are using.

Comment: Just looking at your image it appears as if you aren't perfectly square to the tire. Also you could maybe try to use a longer focal length lens to reduce perspective distortion. If you can mention what you've tried I can try be more specific.

Comment: The photo that you posted as your goal could also be a 3D rendering.

Comment: Also there are ilumination issues that you are not acomplishing, and "make up" on the tires. And Yes, null could be right, you probably need more equipment and yes... I would do that on a 3D render.

Comment: She was hired to take pictures of tires; 3D rendering may be out of her skill set. Is having them mounted on rims out of the question? They're soggy pieces of rubber otherwise; it's natural that they would sag and bulge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this optically (in camera) you will need to shoot the tyre from a long way away using a telephoto or supertelephoto lens. Being a long way away means the front of the tyre and back of the tyre are very similar distances and will therefore appear a similar size (imagine if you are one tyre-diameter away, the front of the tyre will be twice as close as the back).

You will still be left with a slight bulge, but that's easier to fix in Photoshop (if necessary) using the liquify tool than a large bulge.

Comment: Note to OP: This is the exact same principle portrait photographers use to take more flattering photos and avoid exaggerating the size of people's noses or other body parts nearer the camera.

If all you have is the zoom lens that came with your camera, simply try using the telephoto end of that, standing far enough away as you need to in order to get it all in.  This will definitely improve over what you have now, which appears to use quite a wide angle, taken from very close.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving further away and then zooming in. The bulge effect is cause by the fact that you are too close in this situation. E.g you might be 30cm from the closest part of the tyre and 60cm from the top of the tyre. Consequently the top will look 'smaller' and narrower.

Imagine holding up two 30cm rulers - one at arm's length from your face and the other half that distance - the nearer one will look bigger. This is what you are seeing. Think about how far away the rulers would have to be (with one 30-40cm nearer than the other) before they look the same size.

.